# How to determine the types of indexes in a database?

Tags: database, postgresql

I'm fiddling around with PostgreSQL right now.

I can see the user indexes using `SELECT * FROM pg_stat_user_indexes`

However, it doesn't seem like the result gives any information on the type of each index such as 'B-tree', 'R-tree', 'Hash', and 'GiST'.

Anyone know how I can find out the type of each index?

Comment: phpPgAdmin should be able to provide you this information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pg_stat_user_indexes` stores statistics, not the general index data.

Use this:

```
SELECT  i.indexname, a.amname
FROM    pg_indexes i
JOIN    pg_class c
ON      c.relname = i.indexname
JOIN    pg_am a
ON      a.oid = c.relam 
WHERE   i.schemaname = 'public' -- or whatever your schema is
```